# Apache Solr Cloud - One aliases for Multiple Collection

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

We have 4 collection in Solr Cloud (6.6.6). All of these have same schema and hence same type of content. When query, we have to specify each collection name one by one in the query parameters. Is it possible to create a aliases (or something like this) that can route traffic to all collections at bottom level. Due to some technical reasons, we cannot use multiple shards.

It is more like mailing list where a mail is sent to many (mailing-list) users.

Comment: I think yes you can create a alias for all the collections../admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=name&collections=collectionlist

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=testalias&collections=collection1,collection2&wt=xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a alias for multiple collection.

Below is the way you create an alias for multiple collection.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=testalias&collections=collection1,collection2&wt=xml
```

Please refer the solr documentation for more details.
[Collection Alias](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/collection-aliasing.html)